# Replace a word multiple times from ajax response object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a ajax response object say 'var data;' . 
It contains html content. 
In it there is table with id='table123'. 
I want to replace word say 'sample' with 'SAMPLE' form inside that table in variable 'data'. 
I want to replace all occurrence of the word 'sample'using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript [**replace**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) mathod,

```
data.replace(/sample/g, "SAMPLE");
```

**Update due to change in OP**

```
var data = $(data);
changedHtml = data.find('#table123').html().replace(/sample/g, "SAMPLE");
data.find('#table123').html(changedHtml);
```

Comment: +1 for the speed of answering. I see a question, I click in the answer area, and it says *1 New Answer*, and it has to be @Adil. :-)

Comment: I have been disciplined for pointing people towards W3Schools, by pointing me to w3fools.com . Thought I should spread the message.

Comment: @Adil Question modified. Please have a look.

Comment: @FrancisMV123, note the `g` in the regex. It is for global. Without that it would only replace the first occurence.

Comment: @Adil How to replace 'sample' with a dynamic variable from  >>> html().replace(/sample/g, "SAMPLE"); <<<

Answer (score 0):

Create the table first and then replace the text.

```
// used "#id" for illustration purposes
$("#id").append( data ); 

var el = $('#table123');
var txt = el.html( el.html().replace(/sample/g, 'SAMPLE') );
```

Regarding the use of $(data) the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) state the following about passing a string into jQuery()

> if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML.

So you might as well create the element in the first place and replace after.